# Custom Tabbar: adjusting the view of the displayed view controller so it is resized to fit above the tabbar

Tags: iphone

I need to create a customTabbar in one of my app. I subclassed UITabbarcontroller by adding a custom view to it. I made the tabbar hidden by setting

```
self.tabbar.hidden = True;
```

I added buttons on the customView, and on click of these buttons am handling the switching between the tabs.

The issue that am facing is that the height of my custom tabbar is not equal to (more than) the standard tabbar height, so I need to clip my viewController's view so that it doesn't hide behind the custom tabbar

I tried setting the frame property of viewController's view (see below) in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods, but it doesn't work that way.

```
[self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.width, 400)]
```

where 400 = 480 - height of my custom tabbar

I hope am clear with my question..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the proper way to do it but I think this should work for now  add a toolBar of frame equal to your customTabBar and set its hidden property to yes ... I think this should work .. In this way you don't have to re-size each viewcontroller's view